# Sort numbers with thousands separator and strings

Tags: datatables

Any suggestions for a smart way to sort fields which look like:

```
N/A
N/A
23.5
566.7
4,789.5
N/A
```

Is there a sort type that I'm missing. Ideally I'd like to just bunch or ignore the `N/A` and sort on the numeric field. I'm trying from here: https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

I've tried `natural`, `formatted-numbers` and `string` types, i.e. in:

```
"columnDefs": [

        { "type": "formatted-numbers", targets: 2 } ]
```

Is there a ready-made sort type that could help me, or is this custom type requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`columns.type`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) option set to `num-fmt` as shown below.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: 2, type: 'num-fmt' }
    ]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6arajyzz/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but can it be done just for one column?

Comment: @IngusGraholskis, yes, use `columnDefs`  as shown in the answer.